# Can gitlab require validation from lower environments for deploy?

Tags: gitlab, continuous-delivery

Gitlab has a notion of [environments](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/environments.html).  I'd like to define a deployment stage for production, but only allow to run it, if the same commit has been deployed successfully in staging.  Is this best done in one pipeline with prod jobs after staging or is there some way to define a dependency for environments?

Answer (score 1):

Since you can:

- [view environments and their associated deployments](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/environments.html#viewing-environments-and-deployments)
- [query a specific environment](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/environments.html#get-a-specific-environment)

I would make as a first step of my deployment stage for production one that queries the staging environment, get the `deployable/commit` id associated to that environment (part of the JSON answer), and compare it with the commit being deployed to production.

If that does not match, the pipeline would stop immediately in error.